# Two binary operations such that one distributes the other.

Tags: ring-theory

I am in search of a set and two binary operations defined on set such that each of them distributes the other. I know multiplication distributes over addition. I have no idea of drfining two binary operations. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean two binary operations such that you have the standard distributive property holding?

Comment: Hint: think about binary operations on sets.

Comment: Yes. I mean two binary operations such that both dustributes over the other.

Answer (score 0):

For union and intersection of sets, we have

$$
A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)
$$

and

$$
A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)\;.
$$

For logical conjunction and disjunction, we have

$$
a\land(b\lor c)=(a\land b)\lor(a\land c)
$$

and

$$
a\lor(b\land c)=(a\lor b)\land(a\lor c)\;.
$$

For maximum and minimum we have

$$
\max (a,\min(b,c))=\min(\max(a,b),\max(a,c))
$$

and

$$
\min (a,\max(b,c))=\max(\min(a,b),\min(a,c))\;,
$$

and since $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ can be viewed as $\max$ and $\min$ applied to each prime exponent, we likewise have

$$
\gcd (a,\operatorname{lcm}(b,c))=\operatorname{lcm}(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(a,c))
$$

and

$$
\operatorname{lcm} (a,\gcd(b,c))=\gcd(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),\operatorname{lcm}(a,c))\;.
$$

More examples can be found in the Wikipedia article on [distributive lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Examples).